# Spring Boot reading different value for one key from application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When im reading application.properties using @ConfigurationProperties ,im getting different value for one key ('classpath'),all others are getting proper value.If i change the key name  from 'classpath' to some other for eg 'testclasspath' im able to read properly.Anyone faced this before.This im getting from clients machine.

changes the name of the key and it worked.But want to know reason why it fails

Comment: I suspect due to `classpath` being a kind of reserved property, it is part of the `System.getProperties` as well and as such will be overriden by the latter value.

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: @M. Deinum :yes that was the issue.It was picking the calsspath frm envireonment variable rather than application.properties.Is there any way to jhandle this in application.properties itself instead of code change for eg: override.envvariable=false :(

Comment: No. As the system properties are also a property source, which has a higher priority then `application.properties`. There are a few names that, when present elsewhere, cannot be overridden (`env` and `environment` have the same issue for instance.). In general it is wise to give them some general prefix for your application (like the `spring.x.y` properties). That way you can also clearly identify them.